# I upgraded a Visual Basic 6 project to Visual Basic 2008 project and got unknown errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6, vb6-migration

I've recently upgraded my project to Visual Basic 2008 and I'm getting the following errors which I cannot identify, I hope someone can help:

```
AxThreed.AxSSCommand is not defined
AxActiveInput.AxSSDropDownEdit is not defined
AxPVTEXT3DLib.AxPVText3D is not defined
```

Any idea what this is and how to fix it?

Comment: Which OS do you have?

Comment: Thought so...  When does the error appear? When you try to do the conversion or when you open a new project?

Comment: When I load up the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks these are references to 3rd Party ActiveX controls. [ActiveThreed](http://www.componentsource.com/products/activethreed-plus/index.html), Protoview Date Control, etc

You may need to Add/Re-Add the relevant control to your project. Right click on the toolbox so select the items to want to use. If you don't see them in the list to may need to register/re-register them on that machine

Have a look at this page for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973200.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Number 3 [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?661254-Registering-Threed32.ocx-in-VS-2008-Running-Windows-7) seems to indicate how to fix the problem...  I believe some of your controls are not loading.